# jasmine-html doesn't run in browser, but works in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, yeoman

I have an Angularjs project set up with yeoman, everything works fine except for the unit testing part. The testing works in console mode (when I use `grunt serve` or `grunt test` in cmd) but when I try to run the `runner.html` file to view on browser, it doesn't have any specs tested.
My package.json dependencies look like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    ....
    "karma-ng-scenario": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.8.3",
    "karma": "^0.12.23",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7"
}
```

and in my runner.html is like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.3</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib-jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib-jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib-jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib-jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib-jasmine-2.0.3/boot.js"></script>


    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <!-- my angular and other libs scripts here -->


    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="mock/stateMock.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/unit/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/unit/services/survey.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

What should I do to make it run like in the console ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

assuming your references to the specs are correct (they sit on level below your runner.html it may just be that you need to include your source files and vendor specific files.  That is the only difference between what you have above and mine.  The one problem I have not solved with my spec runner though is directives with templateUrls.  This is solved in karma with the karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor plug-in but that does not run when you use the jasmine runner.  Here is a shortened version of mine for reference.  FYI, I changed my yeoman generator to run wiredep on this file as well when adding files so that all files would be automatically added.  saved a lot of headaches.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    ... all other bower components
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- devDependencies -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <!-- enddevDependencies -->
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="app/scripts/app.js"></script>
    ..all other source files
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- specs -->
    <script src="test/spec/controllers/myspec.js"></script>
    <!-- endspecs -->
</body>
```